# WPF Treeview Icon Plus Minus

Tags: wpf, treeview, icons, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm trying to add icons in my treeview but it's not showing up. The HierarchicalDataTemplate is in the windows resources and treeview is in the Grid.

Can any body tell me what is the mistake i'm making?

Here is the XML:

```
<Window x:Class="Treeview.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Support" Height="700" Width="1024" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        d:DesignHeight="229" Icon="/Test;component/Images/Treeview.jpg">

    <Window.Resources>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="questions" XPath="Questions/Question" />

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="rootTemplate">

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding XPath="child::*" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <CheckBox Name="checkBoxTree"  Checked="TreeView_Checked" Unchecked="checkBoxTree_Unchecked" />
                <Image Style="{StaticResource ExpandingImageStyle}">
                    <Image.Resources>
                        <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="Images/Plus.ico"/>
                        <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Open" UriSource="Images/Minus.ico"/>
                    </Image.Resources>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                <TextBlock>
                            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding XPath=@WebSite}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@WebSite}" /> 
                            </Hyperlink>    
                        </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

            <TreeView Name="TreeViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="10,116,0,0" Grid.Row="1" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700" Visibility="Collapsed"  FontSize="15" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource questions}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource rootTemplate}"  >

                <TreeView.Resources>


                    <Style x:Key="ExpandingImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource Icon_Closed}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource Icon_Open}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.Resources> 
            </TreeView>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely with that XAML you have a Warning shown in the Visual Studio Error List like the following?:

> The resource "ExpandingImageStyle" could not be resolved.

This is telling you that your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` can't find the `Resource`. If you move that `Style` to the top of your `Window.Resources`, the first problem should disappear. However, when you do that, you'll then get a warning that the `Style` can't find the two `BitmapImage Resources`. So you'd better move those two `Resources` to the top of your `Window.Resources`:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="Images/Plus.ico"/>
<BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Open" UriSource="Images/minus.ico"/>
<Style x:Key="ExpandingImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    ...
</Style>
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="questions" XPath="Questions/Question" />

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="rootTemplate">
    ...
        <Image Style="{StaticResource ExpandingImageStyle}" />
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

If you find that that still doesn't work, please take a look at any errors or warnings that you may get in either the `Error List` or `Output Window` in Visual Studio and let us know.

Comment: I did put the 2 resources on the top. What about the style and how can i call the style in the treeview?

Comment: I'm getting a error message ''Image' TargetType does not match type of element 'TreeView'.

Comment: You need to order *all* of your `Resources` as I showed you in my example. I don't quite understand your second question... you will be able to apply any `Style` that is declared in your `Window.Resources` section to elements in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Regarding your error: don't try to apply an `Image` `Style` to a `TreeView`.

Comment: I got it. Still i see the default arrow in the treeview. How can i remove that replace with the icons?

Comment: Oh dear... that's a very different question altogether. Unfortunately, you'll need to define a new `ControlTemplate` for the `TreeView` to change its default appearance.